# how can i have an image change into an embedded video of the same size onclick

Tags: jquery, css, video-streaming, embedding

I have an idea where there would be an image at the top of the page with a play button in the center. When the image is clicked it disappears and an embedded video of the same size takes is place and begins to autoplay.

this way i can stylize the image and have more control without having to deal with still frames and title bars from the default embedded player.

i'm not really sure how i would accomplish this. any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the type of player you are using. What you can do is just have a simple markup to display the required image and a play button on topic of it. Now on image click you can initialize the player and play inside the same container where image is.

If you are using `Flowplayer` it is very easy to configure as per your requirement. Take a look at Flowplayer demo at the below link.

http://flowplayer.org/demos/installation/splash-image.html

Comment: yeah that player is exactly what i'm looking for. however all the videos i have to work with are on vimeo